# Could a cloud provider access your data?

Tags: legal

Would it be possible that an Amazon (for example) sysadmin get into your VM (physically by going in the rack where the server hosts your VM, and virtually) and get your precious source code? and more.

Is there any legal close that make it illegal?

Is there any security internally at Amazon?

Answer (score 3):

Legally they can't, phisically they can. 
Its more of a "what do they use that information for" kind of scenario what would give them away if they truly are accessing your data without your consent.
What I mean by this is that you would never know if they are going through your data unless they use it for something else.

Comment: Do you mean "legally" or "contractually" because access to resources you're utilizing is covered by your agreement with Amazon (contract, privacy policy, and maybe state and federal law). Could you clarify what data protection statues are relevant to cloud providers?  Or maybe Amazon already covers this somewhere I haven't seen yet.

Comment: In a nutshell they reserve the access to your VM for troubleshooting. But if you are paranoid about your code, don't cloud it, you'll sleep better.